# ¿A alguien más se le cuelga el browser?

Tags: discusión

Desde hace más o menos 3 meses mi browser y todo el compu se ponen más lentos en Stack Overflow (ES y ENG).  Me da la impresión que tiene mucho que ver con la cantidad de scripts de ad networks que dispara el sitio, lo cual empeora si tienes más de una ventana abierta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo sé cómo pararlo con adblockers y request blocking en chrome, pero ¿Qué pasa acá?

---

esto es un thinkpad T510. No tengo problema en tener 50 pestañas abiertas (no kidding), el problema es si abro muchas de Stack Overflow. Pero, saben, me da la idea de que la combinación mortal es tener 6-8 pestañas de Stack Overflow abiertas, todas con DevTools abierto, todas o algunas corriendo un snippet elaborado para una respuesta... (eso significa 15 a 24 frames en total) en todo eso AdBlock spawnea una instancia por cada frame (pero no devtools) así que son 40 frames andando.

Haré la prueba poniendo el sitio en lista blanca de adblock

Comment: Esto te pasa desde cualquier computadora o solo desde alguna en particular?

Comment: Cualquiera, pero eso no significa mucho para descartar alguna extensión maliciosa pq los browsers se sincronizan. Ya hice esa investigación y no viene de ahí. Cuando mato el proceso en Chrome task manager solo muere la pestaña de s.o.

Comment: preguntaba porque a mi desde la oficina me anda mucho mas lento que desde mi casa.. y eso es por firewalls y otras cosas en la oficina. es solo para descartar escenarios...

Comment: Lo único que puedo aportar extra es que en Reddit me pasa lo mismo, pero allá es mucho AliExpress, Alibaba, taobao y gearbest. Y de paso, es mucho peor con developer tools abierto

Comment: Sin adblocker se cuelga y con adblocker anda bien? yo no lo puedo reproducir... te animás a mandar más detalles? browser, OS, algo en la consola?

Comment: Yo en escritorio navegando desde Brave Version 1.2.43 Chromium: 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit) lo hago sin problemas, sin embargo en el móvil SO Android 9 Versión de navegador Chrome 79.0.3945.136 si después de un rato (minutos) de inactividad trato de entrar a alguna pregunta o recargar el sitio se tarda casi 15 segundos

Comment: intenta con http en vez de https, quizás tarde menos al no tener que desencriptar.

Comment: Si me pasa, mi browser por defecto es firefox, y cuando abro otro browser (chorme, opera, grave) se bloquea, se muere no hace nada, me toca esperar un rato y cerrar el otro browser, me pasa con paginas como stackoverflow, facebook

Comment: Yo abro siempre el sitio con Chrome y no tengo problemas, en ocasiones con una docena o más pestañas abiertas del propio SO.

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente, a mi no me pasa y yo suelo tener más de 20 pestañas abiertas, no exagero, el otro día las contó un compañero impresionado y tenía 31. Qué tipo de ordenador o portátil tienes? igual tienes poca ram o el procesador no es el mejor precisamente.

En el personal me pasa pero tiene 9 años, el de trabajo tiene 1 y no se entera

Comment: Yo tengo 70 pestañas abiertas y no se me traba tengo 8 de RAM y abro muchas mas aplicaciones.